# How do you match the character ^ at the beginning of the string?

Tags: php

How do you match the character `^` at the **beginning** of the string?

Answer (score 2):

i think the simple

```
if($string[0]=='^')
```

In PHP a string is actually an array, so `$foo ="string"`, you could access the "s" with `$foo[0]`, the "t" with `$foo[1]`, and so on ..

Answer (score 1):

To check if strings starts with a `^`

```
if(strpos($subject, "^") === 0){

}
```

or

```
if (preg_match('/^\^/', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, thats what you need:

```
if(strcmp('^', substr($yourString, 0, 1)) === 0) { 
    //Do your thing
} else {
    // Dont
}
```